# running sync code in node.js(sails framework)

Tags: node.js, synchronization, sails.js

my code is:

```
update: function (request, response, next) {
this.del_pic = request.param('pic_remove');
this.data = request.allParams();
this.origin_pic_name = this.data.current_pic;


//Part A

if(this.del_pic && request.file('pic')){
  request.file('pic').upload({
    dirname: '../../upload/images/book/'
  }, function (err, file) {
    if(err) response.next(err);
    this.origin_pic_name = file[0]['fd'].split('\\').reverse()[0] ;
    if(fs.exists('./upload/images/book/'+ request.param('current_pic'))){
      fs.unlink('./upload/images/book/'+ request.param('current_pic'));
    }
  });
}

// Part B

Book.update({id:this.data.book_id}, {title:this.data.title,author:this.data.author,brief:this.data.brief,subject_owner:this.data.subject,pic:this.origin_pic_name}).exec(function (err) {
  if(err) response.notFound();
  response.redirect('/');
});}
```

I want until has not been executed Part A code completely,Do not run Part B codes.
That means First, the first part of the code(Part A) should be completed, and then the code for the second part(Part B) is executed.
Otherwise, the `this.origin_pic_name` variable(in part A) will not be assigned any value. `I need this variable in the second part(Part B)`

I used the promises method as follows:

```
update: function (request, response, next) {

var del_pic = request.param('pic_remove');
var data = request.allParams();
var origin_pic_name = data.current_pic;

var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  if(this.del_pic && request.file('pic')) {
    request.file('pic').upload({
      dirname: '../../upload/images/book/'
    }, function (err, file) {
      if (err) response.next(err);
      this.origin_pic_name = file[0]['fd'].split('\\').reverse()[0];
      if (fs.exists('./upload/images/book/' + request.param('current_pic'))) {
        fs.unlink('./upload/images/book/' + request.param('current_pic'));
      }
    });
  }
  resolve();
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  Book.update({id:this.data.book_id}, {title:this.data.title,author:this.data.author,brief:this.data.brief,subject_owner:this.data.subject,pic:origin_pic_name}).exec(function (err) {
    if(err) response.notFound();
    response.redirect('/');
  });
}); }
```

but there is a problem:
`How can I access public variables from within promise nested callback functions?`

Comment: You can use `async` module for this. They provide multiple ways of cascading your methods. For your use case, I feel `async.series` would be best. 
Check out more: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

Comment: @ khushalbokadey, I edited the question,Please check back and guide me. How can I access public variables from within promise nested callback functions? thank you

Comment: Because of [closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures) you don't need to do anything special to see variables at a higher level. Just refer to them by name. 
TL;DR
Take out "this." in your sample code.

Comment: just looked at your code again. you're "resolve()"ing before you've completed the "upload" function. Your resolve should be inside the callback, otherwise your "then" code will fire before the upload completes.